My nftables fails because it wants a network bridge that does not exist yet during startup
I’m setting up a mini-PC (Unbranded Protectli vault, possibly a Yangling original) to be used as a home router. Everything currently basically work as expected once I manually sort out some startup issue. My nftables rules require the presence of an internal bridge linking some ethernet ports destined to the home hosts, in order to successfully be applied. But at this moment of the startup sequence this bridge does not exist yet. So nftables fails to load the rules and I need to manually reload them after every boot which is quite inconvenient and risky.

OS: Archlinux
Firewall: nftables configuration file (no frontend)
Network manager: systemd-networkd (netctl is also configured and standing by just in case)
DHCP + DNS: dnsmasq
Wifi access point management: hostapd

I use IP forwarding between the bridge and the interface that goes to the WAN, thus the need of the bridge for nftables. The rules for that part are as simple as that:
table inet FILTER {
        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter
                policy drop

                ct state established,related accept

                # It fails here:
                iif "br0" oif "enp1s0" accept
        }
}
table ip NAT {

        chain PREROUTE {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat
                policy accept
        }

        chain POSTROUTE {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat
                policy accept

                oif "enp1s0" masquerade
        }
}

Systemd-networkd is supposed to setup the system automatically for IP forwarding (nftables rules + sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward) but it completely lost this ability at some point for unknown reason so I had to do it myself by enabling nftables.service and populating the IP forwarding rules. I remember having seen the rules generated by systemd-networkd and were quite complex to the point I couldn’t interpret (and remember) them. Maybe those rules were the right ones to prevent the startup issue ?
Also, in the default configuration, nftables.service is set to be launched before network-pre.target whereas netctl/systemd-networkd goes after. I could be tempted to swap the order but I’m afraid to break security or to not follow good practices.
What else could be done ?

try using iifname "br0"

@JaromandaX Yes that does the trick, just as simple as that. I thought that iif=iifname… Yet another mistake to add to my "didn’t read the documentation carefully enough" list. Please post your comment as an answer so I can give your points.

the answer given here does an admirable job of explaining - I couldn't explain it any better and I'd risk plagiarising that answer if I tried

You’re right there is no need to reinvent the wheel, but I think that a very simple answer, and invitation to follow this link to get more info would suffice for my question, and still be useful for everyone.

As @Jaromanda X said in the question’s comments:
« try using iifname "br0" »
The man pages explains why very well:

iif and oif are used to match on the interface index, whereas iifname
and oifname are used to match on the interface name. This is not the
same --- assuming the rule
filter input meta iif "foo"

Then this rule can only be added if the interface "foo" exists. Also,
the rule will continue to match even if the interface "foo" is renamed
to "bar".
This is because internally the interface index is used. In case of
dynamically created interfaces, such as tun/tap or dialup interfaces
(ppp for example), it might be better to use iifname or oifname
instead.
In these cases, the name is used so the interface doesn't have to exist to add such a rule, it will stop matching if the interface gets renamed and it will match again in case interface gets deleted and later a new interface with the same name is created.

